# Javascript/jquery - G+ like reveal/hide bar on certain scroll speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-plus

What would be the best way to imitate behavior of their(G+) search bar on the top, which slides up and down if you scroll in corresponding direction and only if you scroll furiously enough? I'm thinking checking every 100ms if scrolltop changed by a certain amount.

Has anyone seen this implemented anywhere? Or do you know of a better, more efficient way?

Thanks

//edit

Here's how it works, if you don't have G+.. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TaU8W.jpg you are scrolled say 800px from top(screen #1), then, if you scroll up fast enough screen #2 happens.. at the same time if you are scrolling up just slowly, nothing happens and the top bar stays as is in #1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better solution is

```
speed = (currentScroll - previousScroll) / (currentTime - previousTime)
```

it also gives you direction(speed will be negative is you are scrolling up)

example here http://jsfiddle.net/PsrsU/